# javascript function inside an object difference

Tags: javascript, function, object

in short,
what's the difference between

```
var MyModule = {
   func: function() {}
};
```

and

```
var MyModule = {
   func: function f() {}
};
```

I used to use the first way. But when I see angular docs it's is usually the second way. why, and what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in how this code is executed, but the second version can help you with debugging. If you see a stacktrace for some error with first version you will see info about some anonymous function and in second version you will see function name.

ESLint has a rule for this convention. You can read about it [here](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names)

Answer (score 1):

The first on has an `anonymous` function and the second has a `named` function.

Both will work the same. It's just to ensure readability. Adding a sample code to demonstrate both.

```js
var MyModule = {
   func: function() { return 10}
};

var MyModuleTwo = {
   func: function f() { return 10}
};

//both will return 10
console.log(MyModule.func())
console.log(MyModuleTwo.func())
```